# Como posso fazer echo de um JSON em PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

Olha estou fazendo uns testes com uma api onde estou recebendo esse json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "18880.8", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "14088000000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "316267315150", 
        "available_supply": "16750737.0", 
        "total_supply": "16750737.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.74", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.29", 
        "percent_change_7d": "11.39", 
        "last_updated": "1513649955"
    }
]
```

Estou fazendo o código em PHP e gostaria fazer echo dessas coisas, segue meu código (que não esta funcionando):

```
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/";

$result = file_get_contents($url);

$final = json_decode($result, true);

echo $final->{"price_usd"};
```

Quem souber poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você observar o [JSON](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php), a estrutura dele é [ {} ], isso quer dizer que o JSON está retornando um objeto dentro de um array.

Para acessar esse objeto, primeiramente temos que selecionar o array. Dessa forma.

```
$url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/";

$result = file_get_contents($url);

$final = json_decode($result, true);

echo $final[0]["price_usd"]; //Acessamos o primeiro elemento do objeto que está na posição "0" do array e depois acessamos o valor do dele.
```

Answer (score 0):

O retorno ver como um array de objetos, como você dar `json_decode($result, true);` ele vira um array de array. Basta fazer assim:

```
echo $final[0]['price_usd'];
```